# Why can't I log in at my new site drupal 8?

Tags: authentication, drupal-8

Finally I decide to jump in D8. I made a new istallation from 0, directly on live server (manually). Everything works fine until I try to log in. Just get 'Access denied' even with the emailed link from the reset password option. Already tried cleaning sessions, changing password in DB, the /?q=user option, alternate between PHP 5.x and 7.x, the settings.php file it's ok...

Any new idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please follow up following steps in your root directory:

**1. Generate Password**

php core/scripts/password-hash.sh 'New Password'

password: New Password          hash: $S$E6Sv/k4GSGN/INOKfDI41NDGdzZGHZLD48qsMdfrvg8RVFOw7Q5j

**2. Update Password in database**

UPDATE users_field_data SET pass='$S$E6Sv/k4GSGN/INOKfDI41NDGdzZGHZLD48qsMdfrvg8RVFOw7Q5j' WHERE uid = 1;

Now enter credentials in the login form and proceed.